# Pause/resume feature of ActiveMQ not resuming properly

Tags: activemq-classic, resume, pause

The newly released ActiveMQ (5.12) now supports pausing and resuming message delivery to the consumers for queues which is very useful.
The problem is that, when you **resume** the message delivery,

1. If there is a message entering the queue: the broker will immediately send the pending messages to the consumer which is totally OK.
2. But if no message *enters* the queue: the pending messages in the queue will not be sent to the consumers until the expiration checking is performed on the queue (which by default is 30 seconds and can be controlled by the *expireMessagesPeriod* attribute) and non-expired messages will be sent to the consumers afterwards.

Obviously we can change the *expireMessagesPeriod* to limit this delay, but when you need a milisec precision, performing the expiration check every milisec will not make sense.

Is there anyway to force the queue to start sending messages immediately after resumption?

Comment: So you are using the pause/resume for something that requires millisec precision? Thats.. interesting. Maybe you should create a JIRA on the ActiveMQ issue tracker as a feature request for this matter?

Comment: Yes, and it's pretty cool. ok, I just added an entry on JIRA [here](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/AMQ-6000)

Answer (score 0):

Bug fixed by ActiveMQ team (details [here](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/AMQ-6000)) and will appear in the 5.12.2 release.